# Java Switch on Enum Value

Tags: java, enums

I want the user to enter a number from 1 to 7. If the number is 1, print that it is a Monday. If the number is 2, print that it is Tuesday, etc.

The following code compiles, but it is not logically correct.

Please see the comments for where assistance is required:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private enum Week {
        MONDAY("1"), TUESDAY("2"), WEDNESDAY("3"), 
        THURSDAY("4"), FRIDAY("5"), SATURDAY("6"), SUNDAY("7");
        private String value;

        private Week(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // How to instantiate this correctly, so that it doesn't only point to one value
        Week week = Week.MONDAY;
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = input.next();

        // The switch parameter is not correct. This is what needs to be fixed.
        // I want to use this case layout.
        //The enums each have a value. The user enters a value. I want to switch over userInput.
        switch (week) {
            case MONDAY: System.out.println("That's Monday"); break;
            case TUESDAY: System.out.println("That's Tuesday"); break;
            case WEDNESDAY: System.out.println("That's Wednesday"); break;
            case THURSDAY: System.out.println("That's Thursday"); break;
            case FRIDAY: System.out.println("That's Friday"); break;
            case SATURDAY: System.out.println("That's Saturday"); break;
            case SUNDAY: System.out.println("That's Sunday"); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your enum should rather be called `WeekDay` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a method to fetch the *enum constant* based on the value passed in :

```
public static Week fetchValue(String constant) {
    for (Week week : Week.values()) {
        if (week.value.equals(constant)) {
            return week;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now use it like :

```
Week weekday = Week.fetchValue(userInput);
if (weekday != null) {
   switch (week ) {

    // rest of the code

   }
} else {
   System.out.println("Incorrect input");
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `Week.values()`

Comment: Sorry didn't get that?

Comment: `for (Week week : EnumSet.allOf(Week.class))` is a complicated way of doing `for (Week week : Week.values())`

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Create a get method inside of your Week enum in order to obtain a Week by a giving string, for example:

```
public enum Week {
 ...
 public Week getWeek(String key) {
  ... logic lookup 
  ... obtain a Week(weekResult) with that key
  return weekResult;
 }
}
```

Or you can try to use the Enum method valueOf(...).

I think that, with this you have the necessary to start right?

Comment: If `Week` is an `enum` you shouldn't be trying to "create instance of week"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private enum Week {
        MONDAY(1, "That's Monday"), TUESDAY(2, "That's Tuesday"), WEDNESDAY(3, "That's Wednesday"), THURSDAY(4,
                "That's Thursday"), FRIDAY(5,
                        "That's Friday"), SATURDAY(6, "That's Saturday"), SUNDAY(7, "That's Sunday");

        private int value;
        private String description;

        private Week(int value, String description) {
            this.value = value;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public static Week getByValue(int value) {
            return Arrays.stream(values()).findFirst().get();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = input.nextInt();

        Week week = Week.getByValue(userInput);

        System.out.println(week.getDescription());
    }
}
```

I left to you the error handling when the entered number is invalid.

As you can see I removed the `switch` block and got the message from enum description.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `Week` variable corresponding to the number the user gave as input.  
First parse the string input to obtain an integer and then use the `values()` collection of the enum type to get the enum value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    int userNumber= Integer.parseInt(userInput) % Week.values().length;
    Week userWeek = Week.values()[userNumber - 1];

    switch (userWeek) {
        case MONDAY: System.out.println("That's Monday"); break;
        case TUESDAY: System.out.println("That's Tuesday"); break;
        case WEDNESDAY: System.out.println("That's Wednesday"); break;
        case THURSDAY: System.out.println("That's Thursday"); break;
        case FRIDAY: System.out.println("That's Friday"); break;
        case SATURDAY: System.out.println("That's Saturday"); break;
        case SUNDAY: System.out.println("That's Sunday"); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives output `That's Thursday` when the user enters 33 (for eg) `Enter a number: 333`

Comment: Because of  `% Week.values().length`. The modulo 7 for the input number.

Comment: Why? the 333d day is Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum`s already have their integer values, but it's counting from `0`, so you don't need a separate `value` field if you are ok with small rearrangement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private enum Week {
        SUNDAY,
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY;

        static Week get(Integer i) {
            return values()[i % 7];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        Week week = Week.get(userInput);

        switch (week) {
            case MONDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Monday");
                break;
            case TUESDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Tuesday");
                break;
            case WEDNESDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Wednesday");
                break;
            case THURSDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Thursday");
                break;
            case FRIDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Friday");
                break;
            case SATURDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Saturday");
                break;
            case SUNDAY:
                System.out.println("That's Sunday");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple use this :

```
public class Test {
    private enum Week {
        MONDAY("1"),
        TUESDAY("2"),
        WEDNESDAY("3"),
        THURSDAY("4"),
        FRIDAY("5"),
        SATURDAY("6"),
        SUNDAY("7");
        private String value;

        private Week(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // How to instantiate this correctly, so that it doesn't only point to one value

        int dayOfWeek ;
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        dayOfWeek = Integer.valueOf(input.next()) -1;
        if (dayOfWeek  < 0 || dayOfWeek > 6) {
            System.out.println("Out of range day of week");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // The switch parameter is not correct. This is what needs to be fixed.
        // I want to use this case layout.
        //The enums each have a value. The user enters a value. I want to switch over userInput.
        switch (Arrays.asList(Week.values()).get(dayOfWeek)) {
            case MONDAY: System.out.println("That's Monday"); break;
            case TUESDAY: System.out.println("That's Tuesday"); break;
            case WEDNESDAY: System.out.println("That's Wednesday"); break;
            case THURSDAY: System.out.println("That's Thursday"); break;
            case FRIDAY: System.out.println("That's Friday"); break;
            case SATURDAY: System.out.println("That's Saturday"); break;
            case SUNDAY: System.out.println("That's Sunday"); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, here is how you can write it without using a switch.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = input.nextInt();

        WeekDay wd = WeekDay.dayByValueMap.get(userInput);
        if (wd == null)
            System.out.println("Unknown code " + userInput);
        else
            System.out.println("That's " + wd.titleCase());
    }

}

enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3),
    THURSDAY(4), FRIDAY(5), SATURDAY(6), SUNDAY(7);
    private int value;


    private WeekDay(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    final static Map<Integer, WeekDay> dayByValueMap = Stream.of(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.value, w -> w));

    String titleCase() {
        return Character.toTitleCase(name().charAt(0)) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
enum Week{
    MONDAY("1");
    private String value;
    Week(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public static Week getInstance(String value) {
        return Week.valueOf(value); 
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "1";
    Week w = Week.getInstance(a);
    switch (w) {
        case MONDAY:
            System.out.println("It is monday");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```